# How do I determine in parent, if the popup radWindow has closed?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, popupwindow, radwindow

I have an application where the user clicks a button on the parent window to display a popup window. When the user closes the popup window, how can I determine (in the parent window codebehind) that the user has closed the popup window?

This is the code for closing the popup window:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function closeWin() {
    GetRadWindow().Close();
}  
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" 
OnClientClick="closeWin();return false;" onclick="btnClose_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both RadWindowManager and RadWindow have onClientClose event.

Once RadWindow is closed, `OnClientClose` will be called. Then you can call parent page's code behind via Ajax or full post back.

### Parent Page

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager .... OnClientClose="clientClose">         
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
OR
<telerik:RadWindow ... OnClientClose="clientClose">
</telerik:RadWindow>

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ... ID="RadAjaxManager1" 
    OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

### Script inside Parent Page

```
function clientClose(oWnd, args) {
   // Optional arguments passed from RadWidow
   var arg = args.get_argument(); 

   // Here the example for ajax post back using RadAjaxManager
   $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest(arg);
}
```

### Parent Page Code Behind

```
protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
   // Argument passed by child window. It is an optional.
   if (e.Argument == "xxx")
   {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

### Updated: to collect the return argument from child window

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function closeWin(arg) {
    GetRadWindow().Close(arg);
}  
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" 
OnClientClick="closeWin('something');return false;" onclick="btnClose_Click"/>
```

Comment: when you write "function clientClose(oWnd, args) {".... where are you getting the "oWnd" & "args" parameters from (I know you say they are optional, but then you are using them in the Parent page codebehind)?